# How to add anchors to a list of Divs generated dynamically by React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to add an anchor point to each `<div>` generated by the map method in React. At the beginning of the page, I also use the map method to generate some `<a>` links. However, I find that there is no jump effect after I click the `<a>` links.

And here is a code sample:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const arr = [
  {
    title: "1"
  },
  {
    title: "2"
  },
  {
    title: "3"
  },
  {
    title: "4"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <a href={`#${item.title}`}>{item.title}</a>
        </div>
      ))}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {arr.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.title} id={item.title}>
          {item.title}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding *https://* beofre the url where you want to navigate to ! i.e https://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

you could check the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9raijy)

```
import React from "react";
// import "./styles.css";

const arr = [
  {
    title: "1"
  },
  {
    title: "2"
  },
  {
    title: "3"
  },
  {
    title: "4"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((item) => (
          <a href={`#${item.title}`}>{item.title}</a>
      ))}
      <div style={{ height: '1100px' }} />
      {arr.map((item) => (
        <a key={item.title} id={item.title} style={{ display:"block", height: '500px' }}>
          {item.title}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```